# Blow up and strict transform

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the blow up of $X$ about a closed subvariety $Z$. Let $X'=Bl_Z(X)$. Let $Y$ be a smooth irreducible divisor of $X$ properly containing $Z$. Let $Y'=Bl_Z(Y)$. I have the following doubts.

1) I believe that $Y'$ is the strict transform of $Y$ under the blow up $\pi:X'\rightarrow X$. Is that correct?

So $Y'$ is a divisor in $X'$.

2) What is the relation between $O_X(Y)$ and $O_{X'}(Y')$? I am getting that $\pi^*O_X(Y)\otimes O_{X'}(-E)= O_{X'}(Y')$. Here $E$ is the exceptional divisor. Is that right?

3) Is the pushforward of $O_X(-E)$ the ideal sheaf of $Z$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crosspost of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823338/strict-transform-of-blow-up